KeyError: 'pick-number' when accessing custom headers in Django Rest Framework view
I'm working on a Django Rest Framework API and encountered a KeyError when trying to access custom headers in my view. The error occurs when I try to access the "pick_number" header in my confirmingPick1View. The traceback is as follows:
Internal Server Error: /api/wager/pick1/confirm/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gutsthakur/Projects/Betting App/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/gutsthakur/Projects/Betting App/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/gutsthakur/Projects/Betting App/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 65, in _view_wrapper
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gutsthakur/Projects/Betting App/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gutsthakur/Projects/Betting App/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/gutsthakur/Projects/Betting App/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/gutsthakur/Projects/Betting App/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/gutsthakur/Projects/Betting App/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/gutsthakur/Projects/Betting App/wager/views.py", line 76, in post
    "pick_number": request.headers["pick_number"],
  File "/home/gutsthakur/Projects/Betting App/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/http/request.py", line 448, in __getitem__
    return super().__getitem__(key.replace("_", "-"))
  File "/home/gutsthakur/Projects/Betting App/.env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py", line 308, in __getitem__
    return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'pick-number'

In my view, I'm trying to access custom headers like "Draw", "pick_number", and "bet_amount" for processing a user's bet. I expected these headers to be accessed directly without any issues, but instead, I'm receiving a KeyError for "pick_number" being accessed as 'pick-number'.
Here is the views.py code:
class confirmingPick1View(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = confirmingPick1Serializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]

    @swagger_auto_schema(
        manual_parameters=[
            openapi.Parameter(
                "Draw",
                openapi.IN_HEADER,
                description="Draw id",
                type=openapi.TYPE_STRING,
            ),
            openapi.Parameter(
                "pick_number",
                openapi.IN_HEADER,
                description="Pick Number",
                type=openapi.TYPE_NUMBER,
            ),
            openapi.Parameter(
                "bet_amount",
                openapi.IN_HEADER,
                description="Bet Amount",
                type=openapi.TYPE_INTEGER,
            ),
        ]
    )
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        serializer = self.get_serializer(
            data=data,
            context={
                "user": request.user.id,
                "draw_id": request.headers["Draw"],
                "pick_number": request.headers["pick_number"],
                "bet_amount": request.headers["bet_amount"],
            },
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        try:
            serializer.save()
            return Response(
                {"message": "Bet confirmed successfully."},
                status=status.HTTP_200_OK,
            )
        except serializers.ValidationError as e:
            return Response(
                {"error": str(e)},
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST,
            )

and the curl command i used to test the API:
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/wager/pick1/confirm/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Draw: <UUID of the draw>' \
  -H 'pick_number: 12' \
  -H 'bet_amount: 100' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer <your_token_here>' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'X-CSRFToken: <your_token_here>' \
  -d '{
  "is_confirmed": true
}'

I'm not sure why the pick_number header is being accessed as 'pick-number' instead. Any advice on how to properly access the custom headers or what might be causing this issue?

"Note that runserver strips all headers with underscores in the name, so you won’t see them in META. This prevents header-spoofing based on ambiguity between underscores and dashes both being normalizing to underscores in WSGI environment variables. It matches the behavior of web servers like Nginx and Apache 2.4+.": https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/request-response/
